# Can I host a website on Heroku? if not, what would be a PaaS like solution?

Tags: node.js, heroku, mean-stack

I am new to web site development, and I have been facing some troubles to find an answer to this question. I use Heroku, nonetheless, the domain is not completely personalized, and it sends the dynos to sleep if no one accesses the page, therefore, the first user will always face delays o page reload. Further, it does seem to appear on Google.  Can I use Heroku to create a functional web page? if not, which option would you suggest? I want something simple and efficient: i.e., I want to concentrate on coding my site, not coding details to make it run. Detail: I am using Node Js (MEAN stack).

Comment: This only happends to the free tier, if you pay a monthly fee for like the `Hobby` the machine never sleeps. An alternative would be to setup a server yourself using digitalocean or any other webhosting

Comment: thanks, I will consider your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A verified Heroku account gets 1000 dyno hours every month](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hour-faq). A month has 720 hours. If you are deploying only one web app you can permanently host a website there.

There are free solutions that ping your web page in regular intervals to prevent it from sleeping. E.g. you could use the [New Relic add on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/newrelic).